# can we create izpack input panels at runtime, depending on an input file specified by the user?

Tags: java, swing, installation, user-input, izpack

this is a standalone utility. on launching the utility, it asks the user to input the location of an input.xml file. what i am trying to figure out is if there is a way to - **read the input.xml file during runtime and using the data specified within that xml file, build the next user input panel**.

the data specified within input.xml will include number and type of input fields, radio buttons with options' values, password field or text field etc.

in case it's possible the actual solution would include multiple such input.xml files to generate corresponding input panels at runtime.

any suggestions on its feasibility?? (the constraint is using izpack as the base/utility)

---

**EDIT:** nope, doesnt seem possible. in order to build the *dynamic* `UserInputPanel` at runtime, a **fresh compile required at runtime** which would be like **another installer** running in parallel. havent been able to find any easier option.

Comment: *"the constraint is using izpack as the base/utility"*  For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix and provides an `installer-desc` functionality for calling a custom installer of our choosing & design.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: i've kept using-Swing as the last option. i would prefer it if there was some way to cover this requirement through izpack itself..

Comment: *"..i've kept using-Swing as the last option."* Umm.. OK.  Wait ..what?  JWS can (is usually used to) deploy Swing based apps., so I really don't understand what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: what i meant was i could try and develop my entire utility over swing (instead of using izpack at all) but the i think the code would be a lo t longer. hence, last option!